# Can't install OAuth on Linux

Tags: php, linux, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to install OAuth on linux but it isn't working.

I'm running this command:

```
yum install php-devel
```

and then

```
pecl install oauth
```

Then I am getting this **output**:

```
    downloading oauth-1.2.2.tgz ...
Starting to download oauth-1.2.2.tgz (45,348 bytes)
.............done: 45,348 bytes
6 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootmB8jnS/oauth-1.2.2
running: /var/tmp/oauth/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... no
checking for gcc... no
configure: error: in `/var/tmp/pear-build-rootmB8jnS/oauth-1.2.2':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: `/var/tmp/oauth/configure' failed
```

Thank you @Daniel M
Now I have another **error**:

```
 make
/bin/sh /var/tmp/pear-build-rootfr2xXB/oauth-1.0.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/var/tmp/oauth -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootfr2xXB/oauth-1.0.0/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootfr2xXB/oauth-1.0.0/main -I/var/tmp/oauth -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -Wall -g   -c /var/tmp/oauth/oauth.c -o oauth.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/var/tmp/oauth -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootfr2xXB/oauth-1.0.0/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootfr2xXB/oauth-1.0.0/main -I/var/tmp/oauth -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Wall -g -c /var/tmp/oauth/oauth.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oauth.o
In file included from /var/tmp/oauth/php_oauth.h:47,
                 from /var/tmp/oauth/oauth.c:14:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /var/tmp/oauth/php_oauth.h:47,
                 from /var/tmp/oauth/oauth.c:14:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:37: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:38: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'pcre'
make: *** [oauth.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Do you know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: You have no c compiler installed, so the module can't be compiled. Install `gcc`.

Comment: ok, how can i install a C compailer ?

Comment: Try `yum install gcc` - maybe some other requirements have to be installed, check your `configure script output` after installing and re-trying.

Comment: yes i installed, thankyou

but now i get another error


sh: make: command not found
ERROR: `make' failed

Comment: ok i found it, i install 
yum install make
but no i have another error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I succeeded!

I updated yum and followed these instructions:

http://www.codingsteps.com/install-php-apc-on-amazon-ec2-linux-ami-or-centos/

**Also**, in the end I made another call (I needed 1.0.0)

```
sudo pecl install -f oauth-1.0.0
```